# Consume REST service with Java 6

Tags: java, rest, web-services, client, ibm-rad

I'm trying to consume REST service, with **Java 6** on **RAD**, with regular jax-rs code:

```
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://host:8080/context/rest/method");
        JsonArray response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(JsonArray.class);
```

The problem:
It doesn't have - javax.ws.rs.client.* packages;

How can I implement a simple client, using jax-rs with Java 6?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use httpclient. Sample code is here


https://howtodoinjava.com/library/jaxrs-client-httpclient-get-post/

Comment: Thank you, but any other way to do it with jax-rs?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with an implementation library of JAX-RS like Jersey(https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/) or RESTEasy(https://resteasy.github.io)?

Comment: Thank you. Are they compatible with Java 6? I didn't see any reference of Java version in their download page.

Comment: In [Jersey documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#d0e560), this one says that you can use version before 2.6. I think, it should be something similar for RestEasy but I don't find the information.